# jquery post file and button value and get response from script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to post file and button value and process it in php.

Issue is in my php script `ha2e.php` condition `if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {}` always goes `false`

html:

```
<div id="htmlar2en" style="text-align:center">
            <div class="container">
            <div style="text-align:center">
            <h1>  Arabic to English HTML </h1>
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframe4" id = "htmla2e">
            *.XLSX <input type="file" name="file"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" id="submit4" name="submit4" value="HTML Arabic to English" />
            </form>
            <iframe name="iframe4" id="iframe4" src="" style="display:none" ></iframe>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var extra_data = "This is more stuff to send";
   var Bvalue = $(this).attr("value");

   $('#submit4').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "he2a.php",
     data: {'form': $("#htmla2e").serialize(), 'other': extra_data, 'submit4': Bvalue},
     success: function(msg) {
        alert("Form Submitted: " + msg);
     }
  });

   });

});
```

php:

```
    <?php

        if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
            header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
            echo '<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />';
            require_once "simplexlsx.class.php";
            require '../../Arabic.php';
            $Arabic = new I18N_Arabic('Transliteration');
            $xlsx = new SimpleXLSX( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );
            echo "df";
            echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="3" style="border-collapse: collapse">';
            $eng = array();
            list($cols,) = $xlsx->dimension();  
            foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $k => $r) {
        //      if ($k == 0) continue; // skip first row
                echo '<tr>';
                for( $i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++)
                {   
                    if ($_POST['submit3'] == 'HTML English to Arabic')
                    {
                        $temp =  $Arabic->en2ar($r[$i]);                
                }
                    else if ($_POST['submit4'] == 'HTML Arabic to Englis')
                    {
                        $temp =  $Arabic->ar2en($r[$i]);                
                    }
                    else 
                        continue;
                    echo '<td>'.( (isset($r[$i])) ? $temp : '&nbsp;' ).'</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Please check this demo And download it .and modify it . http://www.sanwebe.com/downloads/18-ajax-file-upload

Comment: Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery => You cannot practically do Ajax file uploads if you need wide-ranging browser support.

Answer (score 1):

when you use the ajax request, of course you the $_FILES is empty.

```
$('#submit4').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "he2a.php",
     data: {'form': $("#htmla2e").serialize(), 'other': extra_data, 'submit4': Bvalue},
     success: function(msg) {
        alert("Form Submitted: " + msg);
     }
 });
```

you should assgin the form action to the url you want post data to, for eample ha2e.php, fllow is the code.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframe4" id = "htmla2e" action="ha2e.php">
    *.XLSX <input type="file" name="file"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" id="submit4" name="submit4" value="HTML Arabic to English" />
</form>
```

at last we use chrome developer tools we will see we post the file to the action ha2e.php, if action is empty, the default current url page.
[image]

Comment: in action and `jquery` both we need to give file name?

Comment: @user123   Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery => You cannot practically do Ajax file uploads if you need wide-ranging browser support.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see the answers on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) or on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) - uploading files with AJAX is not working with the generic method you are using.

Comment: Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery => You cannot practically do Ajax file uploads if you need wide-ranging browser support.

Comment: @PratikJoshi: then what is the solution for this?

Comment: @user123 , I already told in Your Question comments, you need to use Plugin "Please check this demo And download it .and modify it . sanwebe.com/downloads/18-ajax-file-upload"